# void action Performed execute multiple time without giving any loop statement

Tags: java, arrays

Each time `actionPerformed()` is called, it gets executed depending upon the number of calls made.

Problem:

- First call-executes once for the call
- Second call-method gets executed twice in a row (consecutive).
- Third call- 3 times executed in a row
- so on...nth call- gets executed n times in a row for the call

For each call, the number of execution increases by one.

I have not used any kind of loops and the closing braces are placed in correct positions.

Here's my code:

```
   public class Opensbt extends SBT implements ActionListener {

    static String selected = "";
     int i = 0;
     int j = 0;

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1581264288151208369L;


 JButton Openbtn = new JButton("Open");
//@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
 @Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     System.out.println("Second");

    AbstractBorder brdr = new TextBubbleBorder(Color.LIGHT_GRAY, 1, 8, 0);
    fileopen = new JInternalFrame("Open", true, true, false, false);
    fileopen.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    fileopen.setSize(200, 200);
    fileopen.setBorder(brdr);
    fileopen.setBounds(0, 2, 145, 30);

    desktop.add(fileopen);
    JPanel jp = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

    jp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 200));

    GridBagConstraints firstCol = new GridBagConstraints();
    firstCol.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    GridBagConstraints lastCol = new GridBagConstraints();
    lastCol.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
    lastCol.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

     List lb = new List(2);

    lb.setBackground(Color.white);
    l_label = new JLabel("<html><font size=3 , Arial color=black><b>"
            + "Open file :</b></font></html>");
    jp.add(l_label, firstCol);

    jp.add(l_label, firstCol);
    lastCol.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

    lastCol.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
    jp.add(lb);
        Openbtn.setMargin(new java.awt.Insets(1, 2, 1, 2));
    Openbtn.setBorder(brdr);
    controlPanel.add(Openbtn);
Openbtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    System.out.println("Somthing");
}
```

I don't understand why this is happening. Why is `actionPerformed()` getting executed based on the calls made or current call number?

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about. Perhaps you should post the actual code you are have trouble with.

Comment: What's the question here?

Comment: Instead of vaguely trying to describe what your code does, why not actually *show code* which demonstrates the problem and *indicate in that code* where the problem is?

Comment: @Santhosh Apna code upload kijiye please. Hame code dekhne dijiye. Bina code ka apka question ka matlab samajna mushkil hojayega.

Comment: Where do you instanciate/use Opensbt ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem lies with your `JButton Openbtn`.
Every time the actionPerformed of your class is called, you add another action listener to the very same JButton. Which means the more often you do this, the more times "Somthing" is being written to the output.

You need to call `JButton Openbtn = new JButton("Open");` again at the beginning of your `actionPerformed()` method.